# nstextview change color some text

Tags: xcode, nstextview

Hi i have a NS TexView:

```
    [risultato setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n<Ricetta>\n\t<numero>%@</numero>\n\t<fbimage>http://www.aletrnativeindustries.it/piccole_ricette/%@.png</fbimg>\n\t<foto>%@.png</foto>\n\t<nome>%@</nome>\n\t<dose>X%@</dose>\n\t<tempo>%@</tempo>\n\t<ricetta>%@</ricetta>\n</Ricetta>\n", prec, number, photo, photo, title, dos, time, ric]];


    risultato.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
```

With the last instruction i change all color in red, but if i want that some text stay black?
i need that prec, number, photo, photo, title, dos, time, rid stay black.
prec, number.... are NSString.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply but don't help me so much and it's a little bit generic.